# Is it OK from SEO perspective to use input checkbox outside forms for showing and hiding a menu?

Tags: seo, html

I would like to use clickable menu without JS on my website using just pure CSS for showing and hiding submenus. Just like this: https://codepen.io/Tont/pen/hdsev

Funcionality of this menu is based on hidden input checkboxes and its checked/unchecked states. Checkboxes are placed inside UL LI tree before subbranches.

I would like to know if you find it good, bad or irevelant from SEO (or Google bot) point of view?

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 3):

Googlebot will find and follow links in drop down menus.   There is no SEO issue with hidden menus and link discovery.

Google tends not to index text that isn't visible to users when the page first loads.    Menus don't have much important text in them.  What text they do have tends to be used in page titles as well.  There is no issue with hidden content that doesn't get indexed when using drop down menus.

Google penalizes sites that stuff keywords in hidden text to try to get them indexed.  Sections that users can easily show via a click are not problematic from this standpoint.  Google usually chooses not to index their content, but it won't penalize for hiding features until a user clicks.  A drop down menu with initially hidden content won't cause SEO problems due keyword spam penalties.

Google doesn't care much what HTML markup you use.   Aside from `<title>` and various meta tags, Google isn't very picky.   You can use pretty much any tags that end up working well for users.   Google has long said that they index the web as the find it, not as they would like it to be.  They have never given boosts to sites for semantic correctness, validating HTML, or good use of code.  The fact that you use hidden check boxes is irrelevant to Google.  You could store menu state in hidden unicorns for all they care as long as it works for users.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drop down memus should be fine for SEO and have become a staple of the internet. I would personally recommend adding a hover menu to it as well.

Google can underst and the difference between expandable content and content that is actually hidden from the user on a page. Drop down menus fall into the category of expandable content and Google knows that this is very useful for users on websites.

Comment: Thanks. My biggest concern is using input checkbox outside <form> tag. Do you find it OK?

Comment: You can use input checkboxes outside of form tags. It is considered valid HTML. This might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572/is-input-well-formed-without-a-form